# Gitlab CE on Private network either is forced to choose between avatars or email notifications

Tags: server, gitlab, gitlab-8

I have installed `Gitlab CE 8.8.5 68cd138` on a machine in a private network. For now, the machine is still only accesible by the local IP address `192.X.X.X`. The instance works very well, but it became aparent right away that the instance was unable to serve avatars because it was referencing their address as `http://localhost/***avatar.png`. This could be fixed by changing `gitlab.yml` in the following way

```
gitlab:
   host: 192.X.X.X # previously 'localhost'
```

However, by changing host in this way, it has rendered the postfix email notifications service inoperable. The logs do not seem to indicate any problem sending emails.

I followed the instructions on this page (http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/incoming_email/postfix.html), but the machine is not accessible from outside the network. For now, I have not setup the machine to take incoming messages, and there is no smtp server on the machine at the moment.

Ideally, I am searching for a way to fix the server's ability to serve gitlab pages (including avatars) with prompt notifications by email that cannot be replied to. I would appreciate any advice on how to reconfigure the system for operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The postfix emailing service was unreliable, so I ended up working an SMTP server into the workflow. However, this also suffered similar reliability issues.

This was all fixed after I moved the entire server to `gitlab-ce 8.9.6`.